# Checkbox tree implementation - get selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to implement a Checkbox tree and I came across this component called [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/checkbox). It is a jQuery component and unfortunately I have no experience with Jquery. I followed the documentation and I have implemented my checkbox tree. The problem is with finding the selected checkboxes upon some event,say form submit. The API says,`.get_checked ( context ), .get_unchecked ( context )`.

But I am not sure on how to use this. In the sense, whichobj.getChecked()? And what is the context here? Can someone care to throw some light on this by giving an example ?

Also,is there any other non-jquery components for this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: any non-jquery components for this--

Yes, use the [YUI Treeview](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/) with [checkboxes](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/treeview/tv_highlight.html)

YUI is industrial strength (it's used on the Yahoo products), well documented, open source and a [supportive community](http://yuilibrary.com/).